# when updating static library, main application has to be recompiled or relinked?

Tags: compilation, static-libraries

Assume there's an application that uses a static library, and that static library is updated.
Besides recompiling the library, the main application must be recompiled or relinked or both (rebuilt)?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library has to be recompiled and the application only relinked.