# static library change will cause ODR violation?

Tags: c++, static-libraries, static-linking, abi, one-definition-rule

Say I have a static libA and a static libB. libA depends on libB, and libA and libB are linked together into an executable.  Now I am working on a new program that also needs libA and libB. The only difference is some implementation of functions (and/or interface which are not called by libA) in B is changed.

As posted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413648/when-updating-static-library-main-application-has-to-be-recompiled-or-relinked), I just need to recompile libB and link the original libA and new libB to the new program.

My question is **Will there be any odr violation or something like abi compatibility problems since the B headers are different compared to when libA is compiled?**

I found some similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55632222/odr-violation-when-linking-static-and-dynamic-library), but they couldn't solve my question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The key point is this: *libA depends on libB*. That means, if you change libB then you should rebuild libA. That's what "depends on" means.

Comment: @AdrianMole You mean it's not possible to share the same libA in two programs in this case?

Comment: Well, things *might* work, if you're very lucky. But, if there is a dependency that you have not taken care of during your rebuild, then you're asking for trouble.

Comment: @AdrianMole Thanks. I know what you mean. If I can handle the dependency problem, will there be odr violation or something?